# merge two objects in lodash

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, lodash

I have two arrays of objects as follows:

```
$scope.var1 = [{
    "field_name": "fname",
    "mapped_field": "firstName",
    "position": 2
}, {
    "field_name": "lname",
    "mapped_field": "lastName",
    "position": 1
}, {
    "field_name": "email",
    "mapped_field": "Email",
    "position": 1
}];

$scope.final = [{
    "field_name": "fname",
    "mapped_field": "lastName",
    "position": 2
}, {
    "field_name": "lname",
    "mapped_field": "firstName",
    "position": 1
}];
```

Here I want to replace final one where **mapped_field** matched with var1's **mapped_field** and remaining of var1 also merged into final one.

Final should be like this:

```
$scope.final = [{
    "field_name": "fname",
        "mapped_field": "firstName",
        "position": 2
}, {
    "field_name": "lname",
    "mapped_field": "lastName",
    "position": 1
}, {
    "field_name": "email",
    "mapped_field": "Email",
    "position": 1
}];
```

Any help will highly be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `_.assign(destObj, srcObj)` ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the combination of `lodash` functions: `_.forEach` and `_.assign`:

```
_.forEach($scope.var1, function(varObject) {
    //find object with the same mapped_field
    var finalArrayItem = _.find($scope.final, {mapped_field: varObject.mapped_field});
    if (finalArrayItem) {
        //merge objects
        _.assign(finalArrayItem, varObject);
    } else {
        $scope.final.push(varObject);
    }
});
```

Link to [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/lamudipuki/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: Its not replacing existing mapped_field in final one. it should look for if there is already mapped_field which map with var1 then remove it and add new one.

Comment: @KrishnaBhatt, I thought that mapped_field is the unique field which shows how objects should be linked. Otherwise - how should I find objects from `$scope.var1` in `$scope.final` ?

Comment: yes you are right. I got it fixed now. Thanks my code finally working.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with:

```
final = _.map(var1, function(item) {
    return _.assign(
        _.find(final, _.pick(item, 'mapped_field')) || {},
        item
    );
});
```

Where you're using [map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map) to create the create the new `final` array. The array that's being mapped is `var1`, and we return a new object for each array item. The [assign()](https://lodash.com/docs#assign) function is used to override properties in `final` with properties from `var1`.

To map the current `final` item with it's `var1` item, you use [find()](https://lodash.com/docs#find). The [pick()](https://lodash.com/docs#pick) function is handy for constructing the filter object. Here, you say that you want to match against the `mapped_field` property.

The logical `||` is necessary for the case where there's no match. For instance, the `email` object. This will just copy over all the `var1` properties into the empty object, and return that.

Comment: thanks. this is the best and short solution. I am reading you book but still on learning phase.

Comment: It seems its overriding the values of final object. There are already values inside the final and I want to retain them as well.

Comment: @KrishnaBhatt, you can change the order of the values passed to `assign()`. The first argument will always get the accumulated changes, including property overrides.

You could change the code to `assign(item, _.find(final...` so that objects from final always take precedence. Or you could replace `assign()` with `defaults()`, which will only add new properties instead of overriding existing properties.

Comment: How can I check if there is duplicate key for mapped_field in final object?

Comment: Why do you need to check? Let `assign()` or `defaults()` merge it for you.

Comment: I have two objects as above. What I what merge both in such a way that if mapped_field is matched with other one replace it otherwise add.       $defaultMappings =   [{a:1,b:2,a:1,c:3}];   $tmp = [{a:1,b:3,d:5}]. what I want a final array with these values $final= [{a:1,b:3,c:3,d:5}]. merging and replacing existing one using lodash.

Comment: Doing something like `_.assign($defaultMappings, $tmp)`. And if you don't want to change `$defaultMappings`, do `$final = _.assign({}, $defaultMappings, $tmp)`. Only the first object argument is changed with `assign()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74220/discussion-between-krishna-bhatt-and-adam-boduch).